# I want to clear the data in the label with the button

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to clear the data in the label with the button. How can I do that ?

I applied the process I mentioned before in the TextBox element, it worked. I adapted the same codes according to the Label element, but I could not run it.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
  {
    if (item is TextBox)
    {
      (item as TextBox).Clear();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The Clear method is implemented by TextBoxBase from which TextBox derives. Label doesn't have this so there is no Clear method defined for a Label. You could just set the Text property to an empty string

Comment: The implementation of Clear `public void Clear() { Text = null; }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label doesn't have a `Clear` method.  Instead, you can just set the property `Text`:

```
if (item is Label myLabel) //Note that we're assigning 'item' to 'myLabel' so we don't have to cast it again.
{
  myLabel.Text = "";
}
```

As mentioned in the comments, this can be simplified to:

```
if (item is Label)
{
  item.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: _Note that we're assigning 'item' to 'myLabel' so we don't have to cast it again._ You don't need to cast to access a property (`.Text`) in the base (`Control`) class where `item` is already of that type.

Comment: @dr.null Thanks, I couldn't remember for sure.